# wpf listview, put image into a column in place of certain row values?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listview

i have a listview, it's filled by values from a sql database.  instead of saving an image for every value of 'x' that i'm looking for, i want to know if there's a way to put in an image to a column for the x value.

so for every instance of "1" in a certain column, i want to display an image of a circle.  for every instance of "2" in the same column, i want to display a square.

if i saved the .jpg file for every instance, instead of the number, the database would quickly bloat up with redundant pictures, so i'd like to avoid adding the actual pic.  does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this, if you use a `ListBox` (which is possibly what you want, rather than a `ListView`), then you can create a custom [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Your `ListBox` would be bound to a collection of items, each a custom type that represents the model that is populated from your database.

On this model can be an `Image` property for example, which could be a path to the appropriate image. In the getter for this `Image` property, you can return the appropriate path based on the integer value (which is another property on the model).

In your `ListBox` DataTemplate, you can use an `Image` control whose `Source` property is bound to the underlying data object's `Image` property.

If you wish to use a `ListView` that uses a GridView, then you can set the `CellTemplate` of a column to a `DataTemplate`, so the principle is the same. This is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750709.aspx).